# How do you override lazy loading on a single LINQ query using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

By default, I have lazy loading enabled on all my models, and that's the way I want to keep things.  However, sometimes I want to eagerly fetch all the data up front on an individual query.  From everything I've read, I should be using `FetchMany()` for this purpose.  However, if I do:

```
var dbRecipe = (from r in session.Query<Models.Recipes>().FetchMany(x => x.Ingredients)
                where r.RecipeId == recipeId
                select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then `dbRecipe.Ingredients.Count()` returns 1.  In other words, it only returns the *first* ingredient of that recipe.  However, if I do:

```
var dbRecipe = (from r in session.Query<Models.Recipes>()
                where r.RecipeId == recipeId
                select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then `dbRecipe.Ingredients.Count()` returns 12, which is correct, however it performs a second query to load the ingredients for that recipe.

How do I make `FetchMany` fetch *all 12* records up front?  I was assuming that was the difference between `Fetch` and `FetchMany`.  I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this by not running `FirstOrDefault` as the last statement. This will cause nh to run a top(1) query which yields wrong results...

Instead use `.ToList().FirstOrDefault()`.

Or you use `QueryOver<>` which works fine

```
session.QueryOver<Models.Recipes>()
   .Fetch(prop => prop.Ingredients)
   .Eager
   .Where(p => p.RecipeId == recipeId)
   .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Works perfectly! (Ended up using the `QueryOver<>` method)